# Network Unreachable In Terminal

Tags: networking, sudo, bug-reporting

I am having issues trying to add a Sudo route in my terminal using Ubuntu in Linux. This was my input:

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.2.0/24 gw 10.0.3.254
```

The issue I was having was:

[MY ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lhk.png)

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

- Resetting my router
- trying to reset and uninstall my ubuntu on the linux
- using another method known as

  route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx eth0

Comment: @rene i have tried to find a solution and have tried these for many hours but sadly no luck.

Comment: @rene I have now added what i have tried however none of these were succesful.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across this way but I'm only going to check the ones that specifically revolve around my question. Also i did check some before so yeah still not resolved.

Comment: @rene thanks for your "HELP" ..  hope you get ur online points and maybe get a yard from that stew maybe even a whip jhz